# gtkmm multi-touch device not recognized (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, gtkmm, gdk

Version: Gtkmm v3.22 (installed via vcpkg)

I've plugged in a multi-touch device that uses the standard Windows driver "HID-compliant touch screen".

I've verified that the native Windows WM_TOUCH is capable of multi-touch digitizing with this touchscreen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-messages

I created a basic gtkmm application and I've called `set_support_multidevice()` on the `parent_window()` before running the application.

However, when I connected the `signal_touch_event()` of a Gtk::Button to a method, there is never any touch events recieved - only pointer-based events that can also be sent via the mouse.

Then to verify which devices were connected I wrote the following code:

```
    // Get the device manager from the Gdk::Display object
    Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::DeviceManager> dev_manager = parent_display->get_device_manager();

    // Get device list from the device manager for type "floating"
    std::vector<Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Device>> devices = 
      dev_manager->list_devices(Gdk::DEVICE_TYPE_FLOATING);

    for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Device found: " << devices[i]->property_name() << std::endl;
    }

    // Get devices for type "master"
    devices = dev_manager->list_devices(Gdk::DEVICE_TYPE_MASTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Device found: " << devices[i]->property_name() << std::endl;
    }

    // Get devices for type "slave"
    devices = dev_manager->list_devices(Gdk::DEVICE_TYPE_SLAVE);
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Device found: " << devices[i]->property_name() << std::endl;
    }

    // At this point we should have printed all devices associated with the Gdk::DeviceManager that's 
    // attached to the current display
```

It prints out all devices found by the device manager for the parent display. What I got was the following:

```
Device found: Virtual Core Keyboard
Device found: Virtual Core Pointer
Device found: System Aggregated Keyboard
Device found: System Aggregated Pointer
```

What do I have to do to get the device manager to recognize a slave device that is capable of multi-touch?

My multi-touch device is being treated as the system aggregated pointer and I can't handle typical touch events - only "mouse-like" events.

Answer (score 1):

If you can isolate the device, you may be able to use [gdk_device_set_mode()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/GdkDevice.html) and set the device to master, which will allow it to handle all types of event. You might also want to use gdk_device_get_mode() to confirm if gdk is treating the device differently.

Comment: My problem is that the only devices I can find with the device manager are the System Aggregated Keyboard and the System Aggregated Pointer. I can't even find the multi-touch device.

Comment: Apologies Austin, I don't know a whole lot about the device in question, Could you give me the device's name and specs so I can research it further.